# CRM responsive form in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, responsive

For a few days i'm fighting with this code, and I can't make it responsive to integrate it in wordpress as a raw html/css/JS code. Could you help me to make this form responsive ? They don't offer support for forms. Thanks.

```css
.pika-single {
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #bbb;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.pika-single.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}

.pika-single.is-bound {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.pika-title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.pika-label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.pika-title select {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9998;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.pika-next,.pika-prev {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 75% 75%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-indent: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: .5;
}

.pika-next:hover,.pika-prev:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.is-rtl .pika-next,.pika-prev {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAUklEQVR42u3VMQoAIBADQf8Pgj+OD9hG2CtONJB2ymQkKe0HbwAP0xucDiQWARITIDEBEnMgMQ8S8+AqBIl6kKgHiXqQqAeJepBo/z38J/U0uAHlaBkBl9I4GwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}

.is-rtl .pika-prev,.pika-next {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAU0lEQVR42u3VOwoAMAgE0dwfAnNjU26bYkBCFGwfiL9VVWoO+BJ4Gf3gtsEKKoFBNTCoCAYVwaAiGNQGMUHMkjGbgjk2mIONuXo0nC8XnCf1JXgArVIZAQh5TKYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}

.pika-next.is-disabled,.pika-prev.is-disabled {
    cursor: default;
    opacity: .2;
}

.pika-select {
    display: inline-block;
}

.pika-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.pika-table td,.pika-table th {
    width: 14.285714285714%;
}

.pika-table th {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

.pika-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.is-today .pika-button {
    color: #3af;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.is-selected .pika-button {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #3af;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #178fe5;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.is-disabled .pika-button {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    color: #999;
    opacity: .3;
}

.pika-button:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    background: #ff8000 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
}

.pika-time {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.pika-time tbody {
    text-align: center;
}

.pika-time-sep {
    width: 10px;
}

.pika-ok {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.TurnKeyCRM {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
}

.TurnKeyCRM label.Required {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.TurnKeyCRM label.Required:after {
    content: " *";
}

.TurnKeyCRM fieldset {
    margin: 20px 10px;
    clear: both;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.TurnKeyCRM legend {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #343434;
}

.TurnKeyCRM label {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 5px;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.TurnKeyCRM label.SetLabel {
    width: 160px;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 23px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM input[type=button],.TurnKeyCRM input[type=submit] {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 41px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 4px 9px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.15) 0 0 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.15) 0 0 2px;
    -khtml-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.15) 0 0 2px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.15) 0 0 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: none;
    color: #666 !important;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#f2f2f2),to(#e5e5e5));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#f8f8f8,#e8e8e8);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f2f2f2',endColorstr='#e5e5e5');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f2f2f2',endColorstr='#e5e5e5')";
}

.TurnKeyCRM input[type=button]:hover,.TurnKeyCRM input[type=submit]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333 !important;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#e5e5e5),to(#f2f2f2));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#e5e5e5,#f2f2f2);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e5e5e5',endColorstr='#f2f2f2');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e5e5e5',endColorstr='#f2f2f2')";
}

.TurnKeyCRM input[type=date],.TurnKeyCRM input[type=file],.TurnKeyCRM input[type=password],.TurnKeyCRM input[type=text],.TurnKeyCRM select,.TurnKeyCRM textarea {
    font-family: arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #555;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 8px 0 6px 180px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM input[type=date],.TurnKeyCRM input[type=password],.TurnKeyCRM input[type=text],.TurnKeyCRM select,.TurnKeyCRM textarea {
    -moz-background-clip: border;
    -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;
    -moz-background-origin: padding;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.TurnKeyCRM input[type=file] {
    -moz-background-clip: border;
    -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;
    -moz-background-origin: padding;
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.TurnKeyCRM .InputBlock {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    clear: both;
}

.TurnKeyCRM .InputBlock>div {
    margin-left: 180px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM .InputBlock>.Description {
    margin-left: 180px;
    color: #999;
}

.TurnKeyCRM textarea {
    height: 100px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM a,.TurnKeyCRM a:visited {
    color: #3679c6;
}

.TurnKeyCRM a:hover {
    color: #D35D24;
}

.TurnKeyCRM .Response {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
}

.TurnKeyCRM .ResponseError {
    color: #B94A48;
    background-color: #F2DEDE;
    border-color: #EED3D7;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.TurnKeyCRM .Error {
    border: 1px solid #B94A48 !important;
    color: #B94A48 !important;
}

.TurnKeyCRM .ErrorLabel {
    color: #B94A48 !important;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny fieldset {
    margin: 10px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny legend {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: .8em;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny label {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny input[type=button],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny input[type=submit] {
    height: 31px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny input[type=date],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny input[type=password],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny input[type=text],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny select,.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny textarea {
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny .InputBlock {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-tiny textarea {
    height: 75px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small fieldset {
    margin: 15px 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 7px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small legend {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: .9em;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small label {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small input[type=button],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small input[type=submit] {
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small input[type=date],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small input[type=password],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small input[type=text],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small select,.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small textarea {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small .InputBlock {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-small textarea {
    height: 90px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large fieldset {
    margin: 25px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large legend {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large label {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-top: 7px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large input[type=button],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large input[type=submit] {
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 18px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large input[type=date],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large input[type=password],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large input[type=text],.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large select,.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large textarea {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large .InputBlock {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.TurnKeyCRM.Custom-large textarea {
    height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://r3.minicrm.ro/api/minicrm.js?t=1470730609"></script>

<form FormHash="29074-1vmo1w4eti26ekzhtj8e" action="https://r3.minicrm.ro/Api/Signup" method="post" class="TurnKeyCRM">
          <fieldset>
                    <legend>Persoana</legend>
                               <div class='InputBlock'>
                               <label for="Contact_LastName_1181" class="Required">Nume and surname</label>
                               <input  name="Contact[1181][LastName]" id="Contact_LastName_1181" language="RO" type="text" />
                                                             </div>

                               <div class='InputBlock'>
                               <label for="Contact_Phone_1181" class="Required">Telefon</label>
                               <input  name="Contact[1181][Phone]" id="Contact_Phone_1181" language="RO" type="text" />
                                                             </div>

                               <div class='InputBlock'>
                               <label for="Contact_Email_1181" class="Required">Email</label>
                               <input  name="Contact[1181][Email]" id="Contact_Email_1181" language="RO" type="text" />
                                                             </div>

                               <div class='InputBlock'>
                               <label for="Project_DataCreare_1179" >Data creare</label>
                               <input id="Project_DataCreare_1179" type="text" name="Project[1179][DataCreare] " autocomplete="off"><script>try { setTimeout(function() { var picker = new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementById("Project_DataCreare_1179"), yearRange: [1900,2023], firstDay: 1, showMeridian: false, minuteStep: 5, showTimePicker: true, format: "YYYY. MM. DD. HH:mm", defaultDate: " ", i18n: {
                months        : ["Ianuarie","Februarie,"Martie","Aprilie","Mai","Iunie","Iulie","August","Septembrie","Octombrie","Noiembrie","Decembrie"],
                weekdays      : ["Duminică","Luni","Marți","Miercuri","Joi","Vineri","Sâmbătă"],
                weekdaysShort : ["Du","Lu","Ma","Mi.","Jo","Vi","Sb."],
                timeTitles    : ["Oră", "Minut"]
        } }); }, 300); } catch(e) {}</script>
                                                             </div>


          </fieldset>


          <div id="Response_29074-1vmo1w4eti26ekzhtj8e" style="display: none;" class="Response"></div>
          <input id="Submit_29074-1vmo1w4eti26ekzhtj8e" type="Submit" value="Trimite">
</form>
```

Comment: best is using bootstrap for responsive.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm trying right now with bootstrap. Ugly thing to make it work properly on wordpress.

Comment: you can simply create a child-theme, and do your amendments there. just copy the header.php, and styles.css files from the parent theme. add bootstrap css and js too, and you will be ready.

Comment: Thank you, solved.